# Find the smallest angle to include all points in a plane

Tags: python, math

I would like to write a code in python that would solve for the smallest angle (θ) that would include all the points in a 2D plane given any number of points. The vertex of the angle is always centered at the origin (0,0). The points are defined using the Cartesian coordinate system with an (x,y) value. A figure below is shown for visualization. Any thoughts on how I should approach this problem?

[image: Visualization]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Convert each of the Cartesian representations into polar coordinates.
- Sort by reference angle.
- Subtract adjacent reference angles to get the angles between adjacent vectors.  Make sure to include the last and first points as one more angle to compute.

Identify the largest angle between adjacent vectors.  The opposite side of this angle is the smallest angle that include all of the points.

For instance, using the canonical representation -- counter-clockwise from the x-positive ray -- you would find the reference angle for each polar vector.  Sorted, you would have the list `[d, c, b, a, e, f]`.

Next, you compute the angles dOc, cOb, bOa, ... and fOd.

You note that aOe is the largest angle of them all being somewhat in excess of a whole radian.

Therefore, eOa is the desired angle.

Comment: This is exactly right. One improvement you can make on this is that you don't need to fully convert to polar coordinates, you only need to compute the reference angles. Also, make sure to discard any points that are actually at (0,0).

Comment: I know; I'm trying to keep it accessible for the new problem-solver.  The computations are a simple matter of computing arctangents.  We don't need the radius of each vector, merely the direction.